# Could this be asbestos?

Tags: insulation, attic, asbestos

I'm gonna get the material tested - already bought the kit. But I'm wonder what people think - I thought it might be old mineral wool since I've seen stuff that looks similar to it. I'd read that vermiculite is hard like pellets, and this stuff is soft like wool, so I don't think it's that.

Thoughts? It's from my attic - old house, built in the late 1860s. There's tons of it up there. It's old and moldy - we had a raccoon living up there for a bit after it ripped through the soffit - was quite a deal to clean up after(I wore a P100 respirator).
[image: Insulation]

[image: Insulation 2]

[image: Insulation 3]

Comment: Asbestos can't be detected by sight unless you see a specific product brand name that has been known to have contained asbestos.  The test is the only reliable method.

Comment: @Kris .... huh?

Comment: @DanielGriscom  lol wrong link

Comment: I understand that it can't be detected by sight, but some people who work with insulation for a living have an eye for spotting insulation that is likely to have it.

Comment: Don’t rule out loose fill fiberglass. Good call on the testing

Comment: I will take an 1/8th please. For a **large fee** you can send it to me and  i will test it then send you the results. Or for a small fee you could buy a home asbestos test kit. *I prefer the former*.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because nobody can determine if a substance is asbestos just by looking at it, and there's no value in asking if you're already going to test it. Adding 3 days worth of guesses is a waste of time & effort for absolutely no value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I doubt that it is asbestos but I would have it tested to be sure. It looks like the pouring wool that my father-in-law used in his attic back in the 1960's

Answer (score 2):

Just thought I'd give ya'll a heads-up since this might be used as a resource for someone. I had it tested.

Turns out, it didn't have any asbestos in it - 90% mineral wool, 5% fiberglass, 5% binding agent.

Thanks to all who commented.

Answer (score -2):

Asbestos is a bad guy for sure, but note that the only people who get in trouble for it are those who had occupational exposure and wore no protection, AND were smokers. If this was my house, I'd either leave it alone, or cover it with sheet rock or plywood and forget it. If it's gotta go, test it or look at it under a microscope. If it is asbestos, in my area, I'd get a respiration filter, goggles, and rip it out. Asbestos is a mineral that is quite inert. It causes health issues because it is shaped in a spindle, sharp on both ends and is thus inflammatory. A healthy person's immune system will simply form a collagen sheath around it and isolate it from causing any health issues. And if there is no respiratory exposure, there really is minimal health risk from a single project in a non-smoker.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but it's mostly correct information. Should have been a comment.